# Grouping of Custom Objects in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I have and array of custom objects of Person Class

```
Person : NSObject{
    NSString *firstName;
    NSString *lastName; 
    NSString *age;
}

NSMutableArray *personsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
Person  *personObj1 =  [[[Person alloc]  init] autorelease];
personObj1.firstName = @"John";
personObj1.lastName = @"Smith";
personObj1.age = @"25";
[personsArray addObject: personObj1];

Person  *personObj2 =  [[[Person alloc]  init] autorelease];
personObj2.firstName = @"John";
personObj2.lastName = @"Paul";
personObj2.age = @"26";
[personsArray addObject: personObj2];

Person  *personObj3 =  [[[Person alloc]  init] autorelease];
personObj3.firstName = @"David";
personObj3.lastName = @"Antony";
personObj3.age = @"30";
[personsArray addObject: personObj3];
```

Now personsArray contains 3 objects of Person objects.

Can we group this objects by attribute like age or firstName ?

My expected result is

```
NSDictionary {
    "John" = >{
        personObj1, //(Its  because personObj1 firstName is John )
        personObj2 //(Its  because personObj2 firstName is John )
    },
    "David" = >{
        personObj3, //(Its  because personObj3 firstName is David )
    },
}
```

I know I can get this result by creating an NSDictionary and then Iterate through  personsArray, then check for each first

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

  for (Person *person in personsArray){

    if([myDict objectForKey: person.firstName]){
        NSMutableArray *array = [myDict objectForKey: person.firstName];
        [array addObject:person];
        [myDict setObject: array forKey:person.firstName];
    }else{
        NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:person];
        [myDict setObject: array forKey:person.firstName];
    }
    }

    NSLog(@"myDict %@", myDict);

//Result myDict will give the desired output.
```

But is there any better way to do ?

If I am using  `@distinctUnionOfObjects` , I can group by string objects only (Not such custom objects. Am I right ?).

Thanks for the answer in advance.

Comment: Thanks It helped for me I want same result of grouping.:)

Answer (score 13):

Checkout this answers it is very similar to what you want

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15375756/1190861

The code in your case will be as the following:

```
NSMutableDictionary *result = [NSMutableDictionary new];

NSArray *distinctNames;
distinctNames = [personsArray valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.firstName"];
for (NSString *name in distinctNames) {
    NSPredicate predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName = %@", name]; 
    NSArray *persons = [personsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    [result setObject:persons forKey:name];
}

NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this is custom object sorting for an array

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Firstname" ascending:NO selector:@selector(compare:)];

[Array sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil]];
```

Answer (score 3):

I have created a small library called [Linq-to-ObjectiveC](https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/LinqToObjectiveC) which provides a number of methods which make is easier to query arrays. In order to perform the group operation you require you can simply do the following:

```
NSDictionary* groupedByName = [personsArray groupBy:^id(id person) {
   return [person firstName];
}];
```

This would return a dictionary where the keys are the distinct first names, and each value is an array of 'person' objects that have the given first name.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (NSDictionary *)groupObjectsInArray:(NSArray *)array byKey:(id <NSCopying> (^)(id item))keyForItemBlock
{
    NSMutableDictionary *groupedItems = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    for (id item in array)
    {
        id <NSCopying> key = keyForItemBlock(item);
        NSParameterAssert(key);

        NSMutableArray *arrayForKey = groupedItems[key];
        if (arrayForKey == nil)
        {
            arrayForKey = [NSMutableArray new];
            groupedItems[key] = arrayForKey;
        }
        [arrayForKey addObject:item];
    }
    return groupedItems;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A Drop in code to help you doing it,

```
    -(NSMutableArray *)sortArray:(NSArray *)arrayTosort withKey:(NSString *)key ascending:(BOOL)_ascending
{
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
    sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:key
                                                 ascending:_ascending] ;
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

    return [[arrayTosort sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors] mutableCopy];
}
```

here key is `key` or `keypath`.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built in group by method in `NSArray`. Your example implementation could be added as a category.

Unfortunately, the `@distinctUnionOfObjects` operation will only return the strings of the firstName property: John, David. It won't do a `group by` operation, nor is there such an operation.

[Collection Operations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html)