# objective-c equivalent to group by in groovy

Tags: objective-c, groovy

Source array:

```
[ { a: 1, b: 1}, { a: 1, b: 2}, { a: 2, b: 3} ]
```

Target dictionary:

```
{ 1: [{a: 1, b: 1}, {a: 1, b: 2}], 2: [{ a: 2, b: 3}] }
```

So i want to have the objects in the source array grouped by their value of `a`.

In `groovy` it's done using `array.groupBy({ it.a })`. Is there a nice equivalent in objective-c?

Comment: Nope. You will have to write your own code to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375528/rebuild-an-nsarray-by-grouping-objects-that-have-matching-id-numbers and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816458/grouping-of-custom-objects-in-objective-c