# swift : Use NSPredicate to filter NSMutableArray of NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

Following is the array of dictionary:

```
    {
DATA: [
{

GAMEID: 509782,
FIELDNUMBER: "KPB #1",
},
{

GAMEID: 509782,
FIELDNUMBER: "KPB #1",
},
{

GAMEID: 509782,
FIELDNUMBER: "KPB #1",

},
{...
```

Now I want to filter the array based on `GAMEID`. For this I am creating a loop and inside that am using `NSPredicate`. Following is my code:

```
    func callSort(arr:NSMutableArray) -> NSMutableDictionary {
        var arrId = arr.valueForKey("GAMEID")
        for(index, ele) in arrGames.enumerate() {
            let str = ele.valueForKey("GAMEID")
            let pred = NSPredicate(format: "ANY DATA.GAMEID == %@", argumentArray: str) // error on this line
            var filterArr =  arrGames.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(pred)

        }

        return sortedDict
    }
```

The error I get is:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse function name 'Optional:' into supported selector (Optional:)
```

I am not sure if I am using the `NSPredicate` the right way.

Where am I getting wrong? How do I solve this?

**Edited Code**

```
let pred = NSPredicate(format: "GAMEID = %d", argumentArray: [str!])

            var filterArr = arrGames.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(pred)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to filter NSArray using predicate on an object property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676371/how-to-filter-nsarray-using-predicate-on-an-object-property/19676711#19676711)

Comment: @DipenPanchasara I want the exact match of GAMEID and hence don't want to use `contains`.

Comment: first question @z22, do you want to sort or filter? `sort`(ordering) is different than `filter`(search).

Comment: @DipenPanchasara I wan to filter out elements(group) based on id

Comment: then first you need to find distinct object and then filter it with matching object. because people can guide you, but not sure provide code.

Comment: you may check this post [Grouping of Custom Objects in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816458/grouping-of-custom-objects-in-objective-c). i hope you get guidance.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara Can you pls check my edited code, I am now ale to fetch teh data using this but all data is not matched, For eg. instead of 5 matching records, only 3 are fetched. Any idea why

Answer (score 0):

Hi i solve this issue in objective c i had same JSON format could you refer this [Searching NSArray of NSDictionary objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846271/searching-nsarray-of-nsdictionary-objects/34289495#34289495) answer? i had used it for search functionality hope this will help you out